# Tensorflow Mac GPU pywrap_tensorflow ignored in restricted program

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, nvidia, dyld

When running `python -c "import tensorflow"` after following tensorflow's Mac GPU installation instructions and building the package from source, I'm getting

```
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH $ORIGIN/../../_solib_darwin/_U_S_Sthird_Uparty_Sgpus_Scuda_Ccudart___Uthird_Uparty_Sgpus_Scuda_Slib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH third_party/gpus/cuda/lib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH third_party/gpus/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow
```

I've tried rebuilding the package a couple times and have been sure to run the python command outside of the tensorflow source directory but am stuck.

Thanks in advance for any ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: where are the instructions for the mac GPU version ?

Comment: [Instructions here (tensorflow.org)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#installation-for-mac-os-x)

Comment: have you fixed the issue? thx

Comment: Quite sure now that the issue was that my Intel graphics card doesn't support CUDA. You need an NVIDIA card as far as I can tell to run tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried v 0.9 ?
`sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl`

Comment: I was building the v0.9 package from source. Installing from the google hosted .whl doesn't provide GPU support. The issue is specific to the GPU version since I did have the CPU only version working in the past

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because python on the Mac is considered a privileged program.  The dynamic library loader won't accept relative paths in the 'runpath' (rpath) for privileged programs.  something to do with a security feature.

when TF is linked, CUDA adds that relative path so that the dynamic loader can find the CUDA shared libraries.  Since it is ignoring the 'rpath ../..." relative path, it cannot find the CUDA libraries and therefore fails to load.

I'm having exactly the same problem. Don't think there is a solution, apart from turning off the system security on the OS.